# Check multiple feature classes have same spatial reference

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system

As the title says I've several feature classes. I want to check whether they have same spatial reference using `arcpy`

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with this way:

```
import arcpy

env.workspace = "D:/test/data.gdb"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

ary = []

for ft in fcs:    
    desc = arcpy.Describe(ft)
    spatialRef = desc.SpatialReference

    ary.append([spatialRef.Name, ft])
    print spatialRef.Name

# Finding the same Spatial Reference Object
for a in range(len(ary)):
    if ary[a][0] == 1:
       print ary[a]

# Finding different form other Spatial Reference Object
for a in range(len(ary)):
    if ary[a][0] > 1:
       print ary[a]
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: I'm just a programmer working on a GIS software. Do `spatialRef.Name` always identifies the projection? Is checking `spatialRef.Name` equals is enoguh?

Comment: spatialRef.Name  will give you Map Projections as Mercator, Gauss-Kruger or Lambert Conformal Conic. if you want to learn spatial reference code you can use `desc.SpatialReference.factoryCode`